# Can we write conditional bolts in storm?

Tags: apache-storm

I just want to know whether we can write conditional bolts or not in storm.
If i have three bolts,1st bolt will do its work and 2nd one will check weather the bolt 1 execution is done or not if done correctly then only 3rd bolt should start working.Does we can try for this,if YES let me know How and if No say why?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In Storm, all operators of a topology a deployed at once and run at the same time... What do you wan to accomplish? What do you mean by "heck weather the bolt 1 execution is done or not" ?

Comment: "check weather the bolt 1 execution is done or not" in the sense each bolt will have individual work to.they are not interlinked(sending bolt 1 output fields to bolt2 not like that). Only thing bolts have to do  is to work one after the other.Just like if condition.if Bolt 1 done its work then bolt 2 have to start working.@ Matthias J. Sax

Comment: Storm does not support this. And I am little puzzled what you try to accomplish... Storm follows a **data driven** workflow approach and it seems you want to get something else done. Maybe Storm is not the right system to use for this.

Comment: okay ! can the ack of a blot1 can be known by other blot2?

Comment: No. That is not possible. Bolts can only "communicate" via streams.

Comment: okay ! thank you @Matthias J. Sax

Answer (score 2):

Can't what you are trying to do be accomplished by linking the bolts together using a different stream id and emitting to this stream id from one bolt to the other when done?

e.g. 
Bolt 1 receives its data from wherever it receives it.
Bolt 2 also receives its data from wherever it receives it, but does not start working.
Bolt 1 finished working and emits a tuple saying "finished" to Bolt 2.
Bolt 2 sees this tuple and starts working.

You can distinguish different streams in the bolt using:

```
tuple.getSourceStreamId()
```

which returns a String with the name of the stream id this tuple was emitted to.